# How to configure nodejs on vscode extension on Mac

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code

i use **vscode** on **Mac** for **nodejs** applications.
I installed the `**Mocha Side Bar**` module, for help me test my unit tests.

The problem is that `vscode` doesnt `see` the '**Nodejs**' installation, and each time i try to execute the 'mocha test run', i am getting these errors:

[image]

The root of my nodejs installation is on that path: `/Users/theodoros.itzaris/.nvm/versions/node/v6.11.5/bin/node`

It seems a simple configuration issue, but i m new to both mac & vscode.
And i did not manage to find any tutorial on that.

Comment: are you able to do `node -v` in terminal?

Answer (score 0):

You can specify an absolute path to your nodejs installation by setting the `program` attribute in your `launch.json`:

```json
"program": "/Users/theodoros.itzaris/.nvm/versions/node/v6.11.5/bin/node"
```

All available launch configuration attributes can be found in [this docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/nodejs/nodejs-debugging#_launch-configuration-attributes).

#### Update

[Here](https://github.com/maty21/mocha-sidebar#how-it-works) is explained how the extension works and furthermore stated

> It will search for the installed Node.js as indicated by environmental variable PATH

Therefore ensure that you have added node.js to your system's PATH variable.

Comment: OP is asking about an extension not node debugging